# Difference between Composer autload classmap and iclude-path

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

In composer [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) section about autoloading I found at least two means to load classes that not corresponds to psr-0/4. First one is to specify [classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) property of composer.json file and second one is fill [include-path](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#include-path) property in my composer.json.

As I can see include-path is more plain feature while classmap caused scanning for classes in specified locations. Who can explain which one should I use in different cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using include-path. It is meant for old software that expects the `include_path` setting to contain some directories, so that `require_once "Relative/Path/To/Class.php"` works from ANY location (think of the way PEAR works). Using too many paths impacts performance, because PHP needs to scan starting from the first directory, until it finds the relative path requested.

Classmaps are an always working solution if the classes do not conform to PSR-0 or PSR-4. Autoloading works by knowing the name of the class and finding out the file this class is contained in. PSR-0/4 define a way to know the file name by using and splitting the class name. Classmaps however know every class name and their file name directly. The bad thing about classmaps is that if they grow too large, they also affect performance because loading a huge classmap and then only using about 1% of the contained classes has a big overhead.

`include-path` and `classmap` are not mutually exclusive. In fact, they might be both needed: To load the first class, you'd need the classmap (otherwise you'd be forced to explicitly use `require_once`), and if that file will load dependencies using relative paths inside `require_once` (and does not know about autoloading), a proper include path has to be set.

If you ever have the chance to change it, I highly recommend to avoid setting the include path, and only use the classmap feature to autoload classes (which means you should remove any include/require functions in that code base). It would be even better if your code can be transformed to be PSR-0 compliant, but this usually is a huge rewriting task for old code with barely any benefit. You'd have to worry about performance only if you really have a HUGE framework with many files and classes - which usually is not the case with older code bases.

Comment: We have at least 1 million lines of code that not correspond to PSR-0/4 autoloading rules. Thanks for expanded clarification.